# What is a good antonym for "symbolic"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, antonyms

I'm searching for a good antonym for "symbolic."

I'd be using it in a sentence like:

> In *Beowulf*, the different manifestations of courage, both symbolic and *actualized*, present an area of synthesis between the real and the imagined.

Is "actualized" a good antonym for symbolic? I've also considered "applied" and "action-based." The above is just a throwaway sentence.

Edit: I suppose I'm trying to get at the difference between courage symbolized through an object and courage performed through a valiant act.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/symbolic/antonyms) are off-topic.

Comment: I also have issues with the excerpt - although that might be just a personal thing it does get in the way of the question posed in the title -  I might consider  symbolic/concrete or symbolic/'face-value' symbolic/reality  for a couple suggestions

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin OP is asking for an antonym of symbolic, not a synonym, so it makes sense that "actualized" means the opposite of "symbolic".

Comment: Oops! How right you are. Thanks for pointing that out. However, I don't think there is any antonym for symbolic", nor anything closely approaching one. Of course "actual(used)" is *different* but *different* doesn't mean antonymous. JJJ's "literal" seems as close as you'll get, but still not close at all.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm looking for advice in the particular context of word-choice in the sentence above. So far I've been unable to find a suitable antonym for symbolic. To clarify, I suppose I'm trying to get at the difference between courage as a symbol and courage as a performed act.

Comment: @spicymage - You need to explain why none of "actual", "nonsymbolic", "literal", "real", "tangible",  et al work for you.

Comment: @HotLicks In the context of the sentence (which I hope I've clarified above -- sorry for any ambiguity), "symbolic" carries a connotation of inaction. So the antonym I'm searching for should carry a connotation of action. The words you've provided lean more heavily toward _real_, and that's not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: @spicymage What did a thesaurus suggest?

Comment: "Completed" or "Realized" are other terms for "state of actually happened"  (lol but 'failed' is another type of completion) -  I would not call "symbolic" an adjective based on "actuality" though.  Symbolism is REAL and exists .... it's just intangible (as @HotLicks just commented - bad synonym for what you want the antonym for)

Comment: Maybe, just maybe you should edit your question to explain what you're *really* asking.  "Symbolic" is a poor synonym for the word you want the antonym of.

Answer (score 6):

**Literal**, according to [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/literal):

> Taking words in their usual or most basic sense without metaphor or exaggeration.
>
> Free from exaggeration or distortion.

Attribution: "Literal | Definition of Literal in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed April 01, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/literal.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're on the right track with actualized, but perhaps [actual](https://wikidiff.com/actualize/actual) would be even better (besides, I really like how it sounds). According to WikiDiff, actualized is a verb, while actual is an adjective. So that would be in agreement with *symbolic* (also an adjective).

- In Beowulf, the different manifestations of courage, both symbolic and actual, present an area of synthesis between the real and the imagined.

Answer (score 0):

**Demonstrative**, according to [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demonstrative):

> Involving demonstration, especially by scientific means.

Answer (score -1):

*"actualized"* - no, *"actual"* - maybe.

Other options for it in your sentence are `direct`, `unsymbolic`, or `nonrepresentative`.